# HTML fullpage.js doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html, fullpage.js

Here, what I'm doing wrong?

I can't make **fullpage.js** work, it is driving me crazy :C here's a pic, I appreciate any help you can provide me.

### [It worked Chris!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fGS3E.png)

UPDATE: That code works!! apparently it's an error on my code, i'll try to solve it, thanks!

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) And the perfect question And how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) SO is **not a free Coding or Code Conversion or Debugging or Tutorial or Library Finding service** You also have to show that you have made some effort to solve your own problem.

Comment: Thanks! i fixed the title, is hard to prove my effort but i did, and im stuck there :C

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that you don't include sections inside `<div id="fullpage">`. All sections must be inside the `#fullpage` div. Just change your html code to be like this and you'll have it working:

```
<div id="fullpage">
    <div class="section">WHATEVER 1</div>
    <div class="section">WHATEVER 2</div>
    <div class="section">WHATEVER 3</div>
    <div class="section">WHATEVER 4</div>
</div>
```

**UPDATE**

My working example. Hit "Run code snippet" to see it works:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#fullpage').fullpage({
        sectionsColors: ['#f2f2f2', '#4BBFC3', '#7BAABE'],
        navigation: true,
        afterRender: function() {
            setInterval(function() {
                $.fn.fullpage.moveSectionDown();
            }, 1500);
        }
    });    
});
```

```css
.section {
    font-size: 3em;
    font-family: helvetica, arial;
    color: #333;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://zikro.gr/dbg/html/fullPage/jquery.fullpage.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="http://zikro.gr/dbg/html/fullPage/jquery.fullpage.js"></script>

<div id="fullpage">
    <div class="section">WHATEVER 1</div>
    <div class="section">WHATEVER 2</div>
    <div class="section">WHATEVER 3</div>
    <div class="section">WHATEVER 4</div>
</div>
```

Comment: @BobMistake then you're doing something wrong. See my updated answer and working example. That is what I changed from your code, the sections inside `fullpage` div.

Comment: @BobMistake then you have an error to your javascript somewhere. To locate that error, just hit F12 on the page and then go to **Console** and check there for errors. Then update your answer and paste these errors.

Comment: Thanks dude, that works perfectly, maybe i'm calling wrong the scripts :/

Comment: Yes, you should check for javascript errors within the browser console (F12). Check your paths for `jquery.js` and `jquery.fullpage.js` and make sure those paths are pointing to the right files.